# How to check for an empty string in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have the following class

```
export class PracticeQuestionsListAPI {
  'list':UserOverview[];
  'page-info':string;
  constructor(public pageState:string, public usersList:UserOverview[]){
    this['page-state'] = pageState;
    this['users-list'] = usersList;
  }
}
```

In my `Angular`'s component's HTML, I want to show a `button` only if `page-state` is not an empty string. How could I do it?

I have written something like this but it doesn't compile.

```
<button *ngIf="!this.users['page-state'].isEmpty()" (click)="getNextPage()" id="next-page-button" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Next Page</button>
```

I also tried `*ngIf="!(this.questions['page-state'] =="")"` but that doesn't compile either

Comment: Have you tried to escape the quotes? :p

Comment: Why do you make your own life difficult by choosing variable names containing a dash, and not respecting standard naming conventions? Use pageInfo, not page-info. Use `users`, not `users-list`. Use `pageState`, not `page-state`. And declare the properties you're using. Then simply use `*ngIf="pageState"`, or if you really want to accept null and undefined, but not the empty string, use `*ngIf="pageState !== ''"`.

Comment: Reason to chose dash is these variables map to json data Received from server. I have pageInfo variable as well. I will use that and see if it works

Comment: You can just use like this `*ngIf="!this.users['page-state']"`, It will check empty, null and undefined.

Comment: thanks. single quotes worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work fine

```
<button *ngIf="this.users['page-state'].length>0" (click)="getNextPage()" id="next-page-button" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Next Page</button>
```

or this

```
<button *ngIf="this.users['page-state'].length>!==''" (click)="getNextPage()" id="next-page-button" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Next Page</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. `*ngIf="this.questions['page-state']!='' "` also worked (inner quotes after != are two single quotes, together they look like a double quote!).

Comment: glad i could help